# Labeled by color range in python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, mahotas

I need help with mahotas.label:

I'm trying to count objects with mahotas.label algorithm. All is well when the sample image is clean. but when there is any unwanted object, I can not make it work.

Is it possible to apply the algorithm only in a range of RGB color desired?

Deputy experiment.

Link:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/www.pokytools.cl/notebook/problema.ipynb

Thank you very much for your help, 
(Sorry for my bad English)